# split a column containing string in json format into multiple columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

So my csv data looks as follow and I want to split the column "properties" which contains a string in json format into separate columns

```
    {
    "35590840": {
        "": "0",
        "id": "35590840",
        "visit_id": "6788545.0",
        "user_id": "279164.0",
        "name": "Processed search#school",
        "properties": "{'q': 'Pamantsan Lungsod ng Pasig', 'type': 'school', 'utf8': '\u2713', 'action': 'school', 'tuition': '0,125000', 'location': 'any', 'controller': 'search', 'recognition': ['any'], 'program_level': ['graduate studies'], 'classification': ['All']}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:52.418314",
        "label": ""
    },
    "35590841": {
        "": "1",
        "id": "35590841",
        "visit_id": "6788647.0",
        "user_id": "279211.0",
        "name": "Processed profile#role",
        "properties": "{'action': 'role', 'controller': 'student/profile'}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:52.487657",
        "label": ""
    },
    "35590844": {
        "": "2",
        "id": "35590844",
        "visit_id": "",
        "user_id": "",
        "name": "Processed pages#remove_newsletter_cta_session",
        "properties": "{'action': 'remove_newsletter_cta_session', 'controller': 'pages'}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:53.161902",
        "label": ""
    },
    "35590847": {
        "": "3",
        "id": "35590847",
        "visit_id": "6785457.0",
        "user_id": "279131.0",
        "name": "Processed schools#show",
        "properties": "{'action': 'show', 'controller': 'schools', 'school_slug': 'university-of-the-philippines-diliman-up-diliman-up'}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:53.517991",
        "label": ""
    },
    "35590849": {
        "": "4",
        "id": "35590849",
        "visit_id": "",
        "user_id": "",
        "name": "Processed schools#programs",
        "properties": "{'action': 'programs', 'controller': 'schools', 'school_slug': 'university-of-rizal-system-antipolo'}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:54.432711",
        "label": ""
    },
    "35590851": {
        "": "5",
        "id": "35590851",
        "visit_id": "",
        "user_id": "",
        "name": "Processed schools#show",
        "properties": "{'action': 'show', 'controller': 'schools', 'school_slug': 'philippine-women-s-university-cdcec-sta-cruz'}",
        "time": "2019-01-26 13:42:54.755895",
        "label": ""
    },
...
```

I have made some changes to the data such as replacing single quotes with double quotes with the code bellow:

```
df_copy['properties'] = df['properties'].str.replace("'",'"')
```

When I execute the code to do the separation which is the following:

```
ser = df_copy["properties"].apply(lambda s: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)))

a = df_copy.drop(columns=['properties'])
b = pd.concat(list(ser), ignore_index=True)
c = a.join(b)
```

An error is generated:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-9f83e5783606> in <module>
----> 1 ser = df_copy["properties"].apply(lambda s: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)))
      2 
      3 a = df_copy.drop(columns=['properties'])
      4 b = pd.concat(list(ser), ignore_index=True)
      5 c = a.join(b)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-84-9f83e5783606> in <lambda>(s)
----> 1 ser = df_copy["properties"].apply(lambda s: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)))
      2 
      3 a = df_copy.drop(columns=['properties'])
      4 b = pd.concat(list(ser), ignore_index=True)
      5 c = a.join(b)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 44 (char 43)
```

I know the reason is a missing value but how can I fill missing values with a custom one like nan

Comment: If I understood correctly, all you need is convert `df['properties']` from string to json. In this case you can do it with `import ast; df['properties'] = ast.literal_eval(df['properties'])`

Comment: @SergeiMinaev it gives me an error 'malformed node or string: 0'

Comment: Before your apply you could put in .fillna({}) to fill it with an empty dict OR you could do dropna to totally ignore the rows with missing data